# Search engine recognition methods

Tags: search-engines

I am facing some problems making my site visible to all search engines. Google is recognizing my website and all pages well. Pages appear in search in 1st or second page. But when i use others like yahoo or Bing it does not appear at all. Is there any specific thing that i should do for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pradeep, Google is at this moment the fastest indexing search engine out there, so even if your site has only one page it will likely be indexed by Google. On the other hand, Yahoo and Bing are not so fast at indexing and will keep your site up to date only if it is big and regularly (I would say daily) updated.

I have a site for 3 weeks, with about 40 pages which is not indexed in Yahoo, but considering how little traffic Yahoo and Bing brings me I am not worrying about it. You shouldn't worry too. Make your site well-SEOed for Google and Yahoo and Bing will follow.